# How to remove tilde (~) from rendered image URL's with Razor?

Tags: razor, umbraco

In Umbraco (4.7.0), I'm using a small Razor script to render images from an image property but even though this method is receiving the correct information, the images won't display; a tilde is always generated in front of the URL but this is actually stopping the image from displaying. Is there a way (or perhaps an alternative method of rendering media altogether) to remove the tilde?

This is essentially what's in the razor script, with primaryImage being the image property:

```
<img class="primary-image" src="@Model.MediaById(Model.primaryImage).umbracoFile" alt="@Model.MediaById(Model.primaryImage).Name">
```

This snippet actually sits within a foreach loop, to render an image if the property has one.

Comment: Wrap it in `@Url.Content()` possibly so it resolves to a site-relative URL? e.g. `src="@Url.Content(Model.MediaById(Model.primaryImage).ubracoFile)"` (As long as that's what's generating the `~/Path/to/File.jpg` value.)

Comment: Hey Brad, thanks for the answer! Sounds just what I need but I'm receiving the error "error CS0103: The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context". Any ideas?

Comment: If it's not already listed in `web.config` `<pages><namespaces>` as an entry, you may need to add `@using System.Web.Mvc` to the top of your page to see that method.

Comment: @BradChristie are you going to make your comment an answer - I know you don't need the rep but I want to upvote your comments

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the code that's generating your `~/Path/To/Image.jpg` is:

```
@Model.MediaById(Model.primaryImage).umbracoFile
```

You can wrap the result in a call to [`Url.Content`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content.aspx) which will translate the result to a site-relative path. For example:

```
@* Assuming that Model.MediaById(Model.primaryImage).umbracoFile results in
   A string similar to ~/images/foo.jpg, the following will work: *@
<img src="@Url.Content(Model.MediaById(Model.primaryImage).umbracoFile)" ... />
```

However, I would recommend reducing the calls to `MediaById` and store the result (while also checking against a null reference--just in case) with something like:

```
@{
  var media = Model.MediaById(Model.primaryImage);

  if (media != null){
    <img src="@Url.Content(media.umbracoFile)" ... />
  }
}
```

Comment: how to use @Url.Content inside a macro script of umbraco?

Answer (score 0):

If you used a code block you could get the media image as a DynamicMedia object, something like the following (not tested it yet) - also the NiceUrl attribute of the media object will be a non-tilde url:

```
        if(Model.HasProperty("primaryImage") && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.primaryImage.ToString()))
        {
          int mediaId = Convert.ToInt32(Model.getProperty("primaryImage").Value.ToString());                                                                                      
          var mediaNode = new umbraco.cms.businesslogic.media.Media(mediaId);                                                                                           
          string mediaUrl = mediaNode.getProperty("umbracoFile").Value.ToString();
          string mediaName = mediaNode.Text;

            <img src="@mediaUrl" alt="@mediaName" />
        }
```

**EDIT**

Just tried something very similar to your code and it worked fine, so it could be a config issue:

```
@{
    var articleFirst = Model.umbNewsArticle.Take(1);
    var article1 = articleFirst.FirstOrDefault();

<img src="@article1.MediaById(article1.feature1Image).umbracoFile" alt="@article1.MediaById(article1.feature1Image).Text" height="63" width="78" />

}
```